# How to click HREF using Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Trying to click a download button on Chrome using Selenium Type Library. The code below is one that I picked up off the boards but I am receiving a Syntax Error

```
Sub Test()
Dim bot
Set bot = CreateObject("Selenium.WebDriver")

bot.Start "Chrome", "https://www.afterpaytouch.com"
bot.get "/results-reports"

bot.findElement(By.linkText("https://www.afterpaytouch.com/images/28082019-FY2019-Results-Presentation.pdf")).click()

End Sub
```

Comment: You probably want to dim `bot` as an` Object` instead of an assumed `Variant`, but that probably will not fix the problem. Please explain what line you are getting the error on. You forgot to include that in your question.

Comment: The error is on the bot.FindElement line - I can open the webpage fine but cannot click the download button

Comment: instead of trying to click it all in one line, set the element to a variable first, and then check to see if the variable gets set to something first. If not, then it could not find the element. My best guess is that you do not want to include the entire path to the element. - https://www.techbeamers.com/findelement-and-findelements-commands-examples/

Comment: Please post the syntax error as well.

Comment: Tried the set the element as a variable but I am receiving a 'Sub or Function not defined error' ```Sub Test()
Dim bot
Set bot = CreateObject("Selenium.WebDriver")
Dim Element
Set Element = FindElement(By.linkText("https://www.afterpaytouch.com/images/28082019-FY2019-Results-Presentation.pdf"))

Answer (score 1):

I would add a reference to Selenium Type Library in VBE > Tools > References then use early bound reference, full url and apply VBA selenium basic syntax to find link by css and click

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
 Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New ChromeDriver

    With bot
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get "https://www.afterpaytouch.com/results-reports"
        .FindElementByCss("[href='https://www.afterpaytouch.com/images/28082019-FY2019-Results-Presentation.pdf']").Click
        Stop '<delete me later
    End With
End Sub
```